# Visual Studio settings per solution/project

Tags: visual-studio, open-source, automation, settings

**I am looking for a way to load solution/project specific settings for Visual Studio (2010+).**

*I know similar questions have been asked but my requirements are a bit different.*

**Here are the requirements:**

- The settings must be stored per solution or project
- I need to be able to keep the settings as part of my source code
- Settings should be loaded when solution or project is opened
- The users original settings must be preserved and restored when solution/project is closed
- Installation of any tools/plugins is not an option unless they come pre-installed with Visual Studio. Projects like http://editorconfig.org/ are promising but until there is a big user base they are not an option.

Just to provide a bit more context... I want to change the "Keep tabs", "Tab size" and "Indent size" settings for Visual Studio.

Comment: Looks like EditorConfig is indeed the way to go, at least now, 10 years later :). Thank you for the question and for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

From your requirements, you should be using workspaces per solution/project

Hope this helps